# How can I retain background after dilating text in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Create rectangular structuring element and dilate
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)


cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)

cv2.waitKey()
```

I am trying to mask the text elements in an image and return an image with just the remaining portions. I have applied thresholding and dilating, but how can I retain the background.

Image after thresholding and dilating

[image: image after thresholding and dilating]

Original image:

[image: original image]

Comment: In the `for c in cnts:` loop you are working on `image`, yet you show `dilate` at the end (`cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)`).

Comment: that is loop i made to create bounding box around text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple approach:

Using the inverted dilated image `cv2.bitwise_not(dilate)`, create a mask over the original image.

```
res = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(dilate))
```

[image]

In the above image you have all text regions and its boundaries masked out.

Now replace those masked out regions with the background of your original image. To do that, first I noted down the coordinates where of the text regoins in `mask_ind`. Then replaced the pixel values in those regions with the background of the original image `image[0,0]`

```
mask_ind = (dilate == 255)
res[mask_ind] = image[0,0]
cv2.imshow(res)
```

[image]